# Jquery and Slimframework - Status Request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, slim

How can I response a Jquery $.post call with Slimframework 3 with multiples status code?

my code is:

**Javascript:**

```
$.post('/insert/table/' + $pedido, table_data)
     .done(function(data, statusText, xhr) {
         alert(xhr.status);
         if (xhr.status == 201) {
            alert('Done');
         } else {
            alert('Error');
         }
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
      });
```

**PHP:**

```
$this->post('/insert/table/{pedido}', 
 \App\Controller\Master\MasterController:SaveTable');

public function SaveTable($request, $response, $args) {
    $params = (object) $request->getParams();
    $logger = $this->container->get('logger');
    $pedido = $args['pedido'];
    if($pedido < 1){
        $logger->error('Arg:Cod Pedido error.');
        $response->withStatus(503);
        return $response;           
    }

    $conn = $this->container->get('DB_Producao');
    if($conn) {
        $tsql= "INSERT INTO .......";
        if(!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql)) {
            $logger->error('error');
            $response->withStatus(503);
            return $response;
            die();  
        }
    }
    $response->withStatus(201)
             ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
             ->write('Done');;
    return $response;
}
```

With this code, I always receive a status code 200 from post action. And I was expecting a 201 or 503 status code.

Comment: Is there a missing quote before `\App\Controller\Master\MasterController:SaveTable'`?  If not can you check you get `Done` back (use the network tab on the browser to check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request and response headers are "immutable".

Instead of this:

```php
$response->withStatus(503);

return $response;
```

Try this:

```php
return $response->withStatus(503);
```

or

```php
$response = $response->withStatus(503);

return $response;
```

```php
// The headers are immutbale
$response = $response->withStatus(201)
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

// The body is not immutable
$response->getBody()->write('Done');

return $response;
```